# Generic function to create controls at runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic, controls, generics

I want to add controls to my aspx web form at runtime using C#.
I would like to write a generic function which will create any type of control (Eg: textbox, lable, button etc).

Any ideas please. 
Thanks
BB

Comment: You mean at "runtime" in the browser (client-side) or "runtime" as in dynamically on the server, so the client will only see the updates on page-refreshes and postbacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, as long as the control types you want to use all have a default constructor.

```
T AddControl<T>() where T : WebControl, new()
{
    T ctrl = new T();
    ...
    return ctrl;
}
```

Comment: David, Thank you. I wan to check whether the control passed in is a text box and set some properties. Below I pasted the code I wrote but that is not the correct one. Where am I going wrong.  if(ctrl.Equals(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox))
        {...      set some properties        }

Comment: Found the answer. if(ctrl is TextBox) {... set some properties }

Comment: If the passed in control is Label and I want to set the text of the lable how can i do that?

Comment: if (ctrl is Label) {((Label)ctrl).Text = "FirstName :";} I get the error: "Cannot convert Type 'T' to 'System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.Lable'"

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could do something like this:

```
public void CreateControl<W>(Func<W> controlConstructor) where W : WebControl
{
         W control = controlConstructor();

         //add control and configure it, etc etc
}
```

Comment: Possibly also a simple `CreateControl<T>() where T : WebControl, new()` for those controls that have simple constructors.  Also, you could probably pass in an instance of `Control` that represents the parent object in the graph, in which you add your newly created control to its `Controls` collection?

Answer (score 2):

Add TextBoxes Control to Placeholder

```
private void CreateTextBoxes()  
{

      for (int counter = 0; counter <= NumberOfControls; counter++)
      {
          TextBox tb = new TextBox();
          tb.Width = 150;
          tb.Height = 18;
          tb.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
          tb.ID = "TextBoxID" + (counter + 1).ToString();
          // add some dummy data to textboxes
          tb.Text = "Enter Title " + counter;
          phTextBoxes.Controls.Add(tb);
          phTextBoxes.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

      }

  }
```

In CreateTextBoxes method I loop through ‘n’ numbers of controls that we wants to create dynamically in phTextBoxes placeholder.